# jQuery.has() is always true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML on one page:

```
<div class="category-products">
    <div class="rugs-cat"></div>
    ....
</div>
```

And this on another:

```
<div class="category-products">
    <div class="toolbar-top"></div>
    .....
</div>
```

And I'm trying to add a style if `.category-products` has `.rugs-cat` as a descendant and remove it if it doesn't. I tried this (executed on dom ready):

```js
if(jQuery(".category-products").has(".rugs-cat")) {
    jQuery(".category-products").css("margin-left", "150px")
} 
else {
    jQuery(".category-products").css("margin-left", "0");
}
```

But the margin is added every time. I'm sure there is no `.rugs-cat` class anywhere in the second page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) will always return an object (a collection). That collection will sometimes be empty, which is what you *want* to test for:

```
if (jQuery(".category-products").has(".rugs-cat").length > 0) 
{
  jQuery(".category-products").css("margin-left", "150px")
} 
else 
{
  jQuery(".category-products").css("margin-left", "0") ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming `$el.has(pattern)` returns true if `el` has a descendant matching `pattern`. In fact it returns the set of elements who have such an element. If there are none, it returns `[]` (empty set) which is truthy. Instead, use this

```
(jQuery(".category-products").has(".rugs-cat").length)
```

this evaluates to true as `[]` has a `length` of 0;

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/has/) says `has()` method **retrieve array** of found elements, **not boolean**. You need

```
if (jQuery(".category-products").has(".rugs-cat").length > 0)
```

instead of

```
if (jQuery(".category-products").has(".rugs-cat"))
```

see [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nm6Fq/)